# perform a get request with spring rest template and check returned status code is ok

Tags: spring, http, rest, sitemap

Its just submitting the sitemap to google so far i have

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity<?> responseEntity =  restTemplate.getForEntity("http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap={url}", String.class,"http://mySite.com/sitemap.txt);
```

How do I check the server HTTP status that is returned?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to a check the server status returned from get request is ok/200

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`restTemplate.getForEntity(String, Class<T>, String...)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForEntity%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object...%29) returns a [`ResponseEntity<T>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) (extends `HttpEntity`), which has a method for retrieving the status code.

[ResponseEntity.getStatusCode()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#getStatusCode%28%29)

You should utilize that instead of `HttpEntity`.

Comment: ah, I was using HttpEntity and couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute request and check response status.

Example code:

```
//when
ResponseEntity<Void> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, Void.class); 

//then 
assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
```